# How to draw these kind of ovals in LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw this kind of hierarchy in `LaTeX` but I am not able to do it using ellipse or any other shapes using `TikZ`. Can anyone suggest me how it can be drawn?

[image]

Comment: Can you share what have you tried so far?

Comment: Only the ellipses?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: You have been told multiple times to provide MWEs. Please do so.

Answer (score 12):

Here's small starter for drawing the ellipses (but not the text and arrows) (My first real TikZ answer ;-))

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0cm,0cm) ellipse[x radius=1cm,y radius=0.5cm];
  \draw (0cm,0.25cm) ellipse[x radius=1.5cm,y radius=0.75cm];
  \draw (0cm,0.5cm) ellipse[x radius=2cm,y radius=1cm];
  \draw (0cm,0.75cm) ellipse[x radius=2.5cm,y radius=1.25cm];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

And one more solution, based on use of nodes and `\foreach` loops:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,shapes}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 0 mm and 33mm,
     E/.style = {shape=ellipse, aspect=2,
                 minimum height=#1mm,
                 minimum width=16mm+#1mm,
                 draw, anchor=south,
                 node contents={}}
                    ]
\foreach \i in {1,2,...,5}
    \node (n\i) [E={7+\i*5}];
\foreach \i [count=\ix from 1] in {RL,KL,CFL,CSL,REL}
    \node (m\ix) minimum width=3em,below=of n\ix.north] {\i};
\foreach \i [count=\ix from 1] in {NFA,KA,PDA,LBA,TM}
{
    \node (l\ix) [right=of m\ix.south east] {\i};
    \draw[shorten <=4mm,->]   (m\ix.south east) -- (l\ix);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

**Edit:** Improve positions of labels. Now are all arrows have equal length and labels on the right start at same "x" position.

Answer (score 7):

You can start from this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    thick, scale=0.5]
    %\draw [help lines] (-3,-3) grid (3,3);
    \draw (0,1) ellipse(4 and 2) node(A){A};
    \node (cA) at (10,1) {comment A};
    \draw [->] (A) -- (cA);
    \draw (0,2) ellipse(6 and 3) (0,4) node{B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also try

```
\draw [->, shorten <=1cm, shorten >=0.3cm] (A) -- (cA);
```

for the arrows.